# handle data from asyncio websockets tasks

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

i've got a script that retrieves data from websockets streams(crypto stocks of course:]), then i need to handle it, but the thread freezes in infinite loop, geting and geting data in tasks. i use websocketS and asyncio as core libs, then gather() tasks of ws streams. i can get data, send it to handler-the problem is awaiting infinite tasks to be resolved in infinite loop('async for' or 'while True' + ws stream connection) As i've figured out its imposible to get current .result() of the unresolved task(Future object is awaited from tasks), but i can send it to handler func... i need to make some calculations with data, got from these streams(each corresponds a task, and gathered together)

i've tried to do it inside one loop, but the code i got was not nice(loop in other loop), not scalable and i could feel that i was doing smth wrong, now i've got this:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

##simple handler, maybe i should fix smth here?...
async def handler(msg):
    print('handler >>>>>>msg>>',msg)
    return str(msg)

##ws connections
async def ws_stream_binance(url=url_binance):
    async with websockets.connect(url) as client:
        async for message in client: 
            msg = json.loads(message)
            strm_data = msg['data']
            strm_close = float(strm_data['c'])
            print('BINANCE STREAM>>>>>>',strm_close)
            await handler(strm_close)


async def ws_stream_okx(url=url_okx, data=okex_data):
    async with websockets.connect(url) as client:
        await client.send(json.dumps(data))
        async for message in client:
            stream_data = json.loads(message)
            if 'data' in stream_data:
                last = stream_data['data'][0]['last']
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
            else:
                continue
            okx_cls = await handler(last)


##some data to connect
okex_data = {
    "op": "subscribe",
    "args": [{"channel": "tickers",
              "instId": 'BTC-USDT',},]}
url_binance = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=btcusdt@miniTicker'
url_okx = 'wss://ws.okex.com:8443/ws/v5/public'


## main func - calculations shuold be made here
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(asyncio.gather(asyncio.create_task(ws_stream_binance(url_binance)), asyncio.create_task(ws_stream_okx(url_okx, okex_data)), return_exceptions=True)) #here everithihg stops #(in infinite loops above)
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

i'm thinking of the ways to solve:

- asyncio.Queue or multiprocessing.Queue to transfer data beetween tasks, but i doubt the data will up to date, especcially when i'll scale the project to 5-10 streams from different stocks(want to make arbitrage bot and every milisec matters)

-global statement for vars - tried but same problem, can't get the value from infinite loop or can't go to calculating while unresolved loop is runing. and i don't like "globals"

Tell me please in which direction should i look solution, maybe can advise me some other libs for ws connection, that can give away values.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: the only way to reduce the code, that i see, is to remove functions, that creates tasks for ws streams, but i think it wil make code less clear. problem is about handling data from 2(multiple) streams, that's why i think it should be 2 ws stream functions here(of course in final version i'll reduce it, add some decorators, but for now this long form of code is more clear to understand). handler function shows that data can go out of the gathered tasks loop, should i remove it?

Comment: trimmed functions,that creates tasks, removed exceptions handling, some more to trim?

Comment: Yes, that's better. I have given your question an upvote.